# Test with Mocha for throw in asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, mocha.js

I try to test the validation of my MongoDB Mangoose model using the mocha framework.

```
describe 'User', ->
  describe 'create', ->
    it 'should reject a user with an already existing mail', (done) ->
      User.create
        mail: "minimal@gmail.com"
      , (err) ->
          if err then done() else done(false)
```

I expect a validation error issues by Mongoose, because this mail is already taken, but the field was marked as unique.

How can I test for the specific error? I thought the most cleanest way would be to use `should.throws(callback, message-regexp)`, however, this doesn't work because Model#create is asynchronous.

#### References (that didn't helped me)

- [Testing for an Asynchronous throw in Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787235/testing-for-an-asynchronous-throw-in-mocha)
- http://shouldjs.github.io/#should-throws

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `done()` callback. The first parameter checks for an error, and it must be true-y in case of error. In your code, you're always passing false-y values, which means that the test run successfully.

In your case, you want to use:

```
if err then done() else done(true)
```

Instead of true, you can add a string or anything else.

### EDIT

Async functions normally do not *throw* errors. Errors are *thrown* when you actually use an exception (`throw new Error(...)`). Mongoose, instead, just calls the callback passing a non-false value to the `err` parameter (the first one). So, just check if `err.toString()` or `err.message` match your search string.

For example, on your callback (assuming you're using Should.js, as your comments makes me think; otherwise, convert this to whatever other framework you implemented)

```
should(err).be.not.empty
err.toString().should.match(/ValidationError/)
```

(that's all!)

Comment: With this solution, my test would validate any kind of error. I would like to know how I can precisely demand a ValidationError that is generated by mongoose. These is something like `should.throws(block, [error], [message])`. However, this doesn't work out of the box for async tests.

Comment: Ok, so you should not test for "should.throws", because Mongoose doesn't **throw** errors. Instead, just test in the callback if `err.toString()` or `err.message` matches the value you want. I've updated the answer.